# How to get the value of dynamically created text box by clicking dynamically created button in java script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my index.php i have div#card which are dynamically created by php, in div#contents, after getting the values from the database. But when i click on the any of the two buttons to get the those values in javascript, it only gets the input values of the first div#card. I want that if i click on a button, it will get the input values within it's parent div#card element.

index.php

```
<div id='contents'>
    <div id='card'>
        <input id='p_id' type='hidden' value='1' name='productID' />
        <input id='name' type='text' value='Toshiba' name='product_name' />
        <input id='qty' type='text' value='1' name='qty' />
        <button id='1' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
    </div>
    <div id='card'>
        <input id='p_id' type='hidden' value='2' name='productID' />
        <input id='name' type='text' value='Dell' name='product_name' />
        <input id='qty' type='text' value='3' name='qty' />
        <button id='2' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get').click(function() {
        var id = $('#p_id').val();
        var pname = $('#name').val();
        var qty = $('#qty').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: {
                'name': pname,
                'id': id,
                'qty': qty
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

action.php

```
<?php 
      echo "there are ".$_POST['qty']." ".$_POST['name']." in the database";
?>
```

Comment: `id` is to be unique. One of the problems here is that you have multiple elements with the same id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use same id for multiple elements. id used for referring single element. If you want to group elements under same name use `class` And also for input elements use `name` instead of id or class. You can get the value from its name.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).siblings("input[name='p_id']").val();
        var pname = $(this).siblings("input[name='name']").val();
        var qty = $(this).siblings("input[name='qty']").val();
        var data = {
            'name': pname,
            'id': id,
            'qty': qty
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='contents'>
   <div class='card'>
      <input name='p_id' type='hidden' value='1' name='productID' />
      <input name='name' type='text' value='Toshiba' name='product_name' />
      <input name='qty' type='text' value='1' name='qty' />
      <button id='1' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
   </div>
   <div class='card'>
      <input name='p_id' type='hidden' value='2' name='productID' />
      <input name='name' type='text' value='Dell' name='product_name' />
      <input name='qty' type='text' value='3' name='qty' />
      <button id='2' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please avoid using repeated IDs, that's what classes are for.

Instead of `id="p_id"` use `class="p_id"` and do that for all the cases where you're repeating IDs in your HTML tags.

After doing that, you can do something like this in your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.get').click(function(){

                    //This is to get the container div of the clicked button so we can work only within it
                    var context = $(this).parent();

                    //Look at the second parameter of the jQuery selector
                    var id = $('.p_id', context).val();
                    var pname = $('.name', context).val();
                    var qty = $('.qty', context).val();

                    $.ajax({
                            type:'post',
                            url:'action.php',
                            data:{ 'name': pname, 'id': id, 'qty': qty},
                            success: function(response){
                                 alert(response);
                            }
                    });
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `click` function, you should reference `this` to access the clicked element, so that you can access its parent and find the appropriate `p_id` element.

But having duplicate IDs in a single HTML document is invalid - you should use class names instead.

```js
$('.get').click(function() {
  const parent = $(this).parent();
  const id = parent.find('.p_id').val();
  const pname = parent.find('.name').val();
  const qty = parent.find('.qty').val();
  console.log('id ' + id + ' pname ' + pname + ' qty ' + qty);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='contents'>
  <div id='card'>
    <input class='p_id' type='hidden' value='1' name='productID' />
    <input class='name' type='text' value='Toshiba' name='product_name' />
    <input class='qty' type='text' value='1' name='qty' />
    <button id='1' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
  </div>

  <div id='card'>
    <input class='p_id' type='hidden' value='2' name='productID' />
    <input class='name' type=' text ' value='Dell ' name='product_name' />
    <input class='qty' type='text ' value='3 ' name='qty' />
    <button id='2 ' class='get ' name='get '>Get</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But there's definitely no need for jQuery for something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.get').forEach((get) => {
  get.onclick = () => {
    const parent = get.parentElement;
    const id = parent.querySelector('.p_id').value;
    const pname = parent.querySelector('.name').value;
    const qty = parent.querySelector('.qty').value;
    console.log('id ' + id + ' pname ' + pname + ' qty ' + qty);
  };
});
```

```html
<div id='contents'>
  <div id='card'>
    <input class='p_id' type='hidden' value='1' name='productID' />
    <input class='name' type='text' value='Toshiba' name='product_name' />
    <input class='qty' type='text' value='1' name='qty' />
    <button id='1' class='get' name='get'>Get</button>
  </div>

  <div id='card'>
    <input class='p_id' type='hidden' value='2' name='productID' />
    <input class='name' type=' text ' value='Dell ' name='product_name' />
    <input class='qty' type='text ' value='3 ' name='qty' />
    <button id='2 ' class='get ' name='get '>Get</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You also need to fix your HTML: `<input id='name type=` The `id` is missing an ending quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.get').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).closest('#card').find('#p_id').val();
        var pname = $(this).closest('#card').find('#name').val();
        var qty = $(this).closest('#card').find('#qty').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'action.php',
            data: {
                'name': pname,
                'id': id,
                'qty': qty
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```